# PXE Images Losing Active Directory Trust

Tags: active-directory, pxe-boot, entra-domain-services, ipxe

I'm using a PXE booting system which relies on Windows 10 VHDs to boot from in order to image across all our clients with a clean image upon every reboot. Problem is we rely on Active Directory for users and other provisioning but our images keep losing "Trust Relationship between this workstation and the domain" which I know is a common error due to duplicate SIDs.

On startup the system does rename the devices so they show up as:

PC1.DOMAIN.LOCAL

PC2.DOMAIN.LOCAL

etc.

All computers boot fine but when attempting to login we get the above quoted error, I've looked into options like sysprep which isn't all to viable when it creates .WIM and we use pre-made VHD to boot from, I've also looked into NewSID but have noticed a lot of talk about the deprecation due to it not being an issue. Any thoughts on how we can do this?

Comment: You will need to have one snapshot for each client, the client will also need to be able to get new machine passwords, so there is no way to keep one image only and only use in memory changes if joined to AD.